# E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this error:

```
E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:
```

I am working on AndroidStudio with kotlin, the main problem is there is a captcha coming on everytime a I try to login via firebase phone auth.

Things done:

1. Added all keys in the firebase project (SHA-1, SHA-256 -- both debug and release)
2. Enabled Android Device Verification

And when `implementation androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0` is removed, the following error shows up.

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/browser/customtabs/CustomTabsIntent$Builder;`

I concluded, if `E/zzf: Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7:` error is solved, all the other errors will be solved automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Based upon error code 7 and your attempts so far, the client appears to be out-of-sync with the back-end. Make sure to download the current `google-services.json` and overwrite the existing one file in your project; then build again and it should work out. If it doesn't, also delete all `build` directories and Gradle caches. Hope that my common sense will count as "reputable source", because this is not really documented anywhere, except the default setup instructions.

I've even found some "[reputable source](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7015592)":

> Make sure that you only have this most recent downloaded config file in your app.

Comment: redownload the `google-services.json ` and replace it with existing worked for me.
Thanks @Martin

Comment: In my case, this was just a warning and was not the main source of my problems (just another warning in the logs).

Answer (score 1):

### Register your App from the Firebase console for SafetyNet

#### Follow these steps

1. Open Firebase console
2. Navigate to project settings
3. Navigate to App Check and found `Your apps` section
4. Click on your App and add `SafetyNet`
5. Add `SHA-256 certificate fingerprint`

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin, I Solving this Error By Adding SHA-1 Key into the Firebase. Then after All the Errors are solved.

1. Open Android Studio
2. Select Gradle in Android Studio from right Panel.
3. Select Your App.
4. In Tasks -> android-> click on signing Report
   It Will Automatic Generate SHA-1 Key.Add SHA-1 In Firebase Project Setting.

And Also I Add setActivity(this.requireActivity()) in sendVerificationCode() function.

```
`private fun sendVerificationCode(number: String) {

    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(mAuth)
        .setPhoneNumber(number)
        .setTimeout(10L,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .setActivity(this.requireActivity())
        .setCallbacks(callback)
        .build()

    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
}`
```