# Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add firebase auth in my project.But getting the following error.

Problem retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7

I added  `implementation "androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0"` library.Still getting the above error.

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403407/e-zzf-problem-retrieving-safetynet-token-7-android

Comment: Token 7 is related to network error check here https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha  I had to face the issue once as well, cleared the app data and cleaned the android studio project to solve this issue